# Disable IOS Scroll When Drawing With iPad On HTML Canvas

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad

I am trying to create a canvas in html that the user can draw on. It works fine with any mouse-device like a pc or max. It also works fine with a non-ios touch devices (like an android/windows tablet). But with ios-touch devices (like an ipad or iphone) it doesn't work. When you try to draw, it scrolls the page while you draw. Any idea how to disable this scrolling action on ios devices while drawing on the canvas?

Here is an example of a html drawing canvas http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/ Try and draw on one of the canvases on an ipad or iphone, BUT NOT THE FIRST DEMO, for some reason the first demo works but none of the others work.

Comment: Add `whateverViewHasAScroll.isScrollEnabled = false` when or where appropriate.

Comment: I'm sure you're using touch event listeners. If you return false from your callback the event propagation should stop and the event is ignored by further elements

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using `onTouchStart`, `onTouchMove`, `onTouchEnd`.

For `onTouchMove`, you'll get an array of `changedTouches`. For pen usage, the first one will do since there won't be multiple touch events at a time.

```
const position = { x: event.changedTouches[0].pageX, y: event.changedTouches[0].pageY };
```